# OpenCV circle distortion detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

OpenCV has capapabilities to compensate for distortion in patterns, such as a this board, for example:

[image]

Every example I ever saw for this process does it with grids or squares. I would like to know if something similar exists for a single circle. My practical case is that I detect an ellipse, and I need to calculate the angle between the plane of this ellipse and the projection plane where the ellipse is projected as a circle. I managed to achieve that in my own code, but I would like to know if there is something built into the library to that purpose.

Comment: The ellipse you have, do you have a parametric estimate of it ? (Big/small axis orientation AND norm)

Comment: @Jiby I currently do use the axes norms. Of course, I could put together a function returning those parameters you cite

Comment: Nice enough : forgetting your ellipse and focusing on the axes that define it : You have a 2D orthogonal referential (flat circle) with unit norm, and the projected axes (non orthogonal and non-unit normed) ... Didn't you just solve your problem already ? =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use the ellipse axes to your advantage

I don't know of any "circular projection" as you name it, but I'm thinking that you can rephrase your problem into having the solution already.

[image]
*Images make any answer SO cool.*

#### Forget the ellipse, take the axes

A circle can be thought of as 2 vectors with unit norm defining a plane.

**The projected circle's axes you estimate are the projection of the unit referential into the 3D plane**

Then for projecting back and forth is just an affair of applying the transformation described by the estimated axes vectors